# app crashes when opening

Tags: android, crash

I'm trying to make an app which triggers sound when button is clicked. But my app crashes everytime when I open the app, the problem with the java code because when I delete the code, it runs fine.

My Code is.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout hello;
    Button btn;
    MediaPlayer sound;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sound.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kick);
                mp.start();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**logcat:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sp.umavibe.com.sp404/sp.umavibe.com.sp404.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at sp.umavibe.com.sp404.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6116)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
    at             android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

Please Guide me, where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: obviously view with id: `R.id.btn` is not a part of `R.layout.activity_main` layout, end of story

Answer (score 0):

The error is at the button initialization

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

Make sure you have created a button in the `activity_main.xml` with the id `btn`.